# Where is Minecraft Bedrock Edition folder?

Tags: pc, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Having the same problem as many others seem to be having on here, but I'm stuck at a point at which everyone else seems to find what they are looking for.

Trying to install forge for Minecraft but as every guide says I've to make copies of all the game files which I'm trying to do but there is no Minecraft folder when I go looking. I've tried the `%appdata%` search and it returns nothing.

I had a thought, is it because my kids who play Minecraft don't play online, as they don't have an Xbox live account to sign-in to create saves from? Are they effectively playing as "guests"? If so, is the only way to fix this to get them Xbox live subscriptions? Its the Windows 10 edition (aka Bedrock edition) we have, is it better to try and use the Java Edition?

Comment: Do you play the java edition? Or the windows 10 edition? The java edition creates a .minecraft folder in your appdata, but I'm not sure if the windows 10 edition does

Comment: Windows 10 edition creates a folder at %localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\ ,but it uses minecraft pocket edition format

Comment: Dupe links to the wrong version. This one is about Win 10, not Java.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows to find Minecraft folder press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open "Run" and there type `%appdata%` and there should be `.minecraft` folder.

> I had a thought, is it because my kids who play Minecraft don't play online, as they don't have an Xbox live account to sign in to create saves from? Are they effectively playing as "guests"? If so, is the only way to fix this is to get them Xbox live subscriptions?

This is not applicable to Minecraft PC (aka Java Edition), because Minecraft PC doesn't have any Xbox integration, you maybe are referring to Minecraft Windows 10 Edition (aka Bedrock Edition) - (if it is so please edit question acordingly).

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot run `run` command, then go into your main drive `C:/`, then you have to go into `Users` then into `Your name`, then into `Appdata` and `Roaming`, there is a `.minecraft` folder (so `C:/Users/<Name>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft`).
BUT! if there is no mod folder, well, you have to create one. You create a folder named `mods`. Then if you download a mod you have to make sure that your Forge version is the same as the mod, then when installed you move the Mod into your mods folder, run Minecraft in the Forge version _____, let it load and there you go!

Here is one mostly asked question:

- The mod cannot be run but the version is the same!

  - If you have a 1.12.2 Forge and a 1.10 Mod in the mods folder, Minecraft Forge tries to run BOTH of them, you might keep them in a special folder (the other mods) when you need it, they are there!

If you have more question, just ask me.